# How can I implement delete object using ajax in Django?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, django, django-rest-framework

I already implemented `create`, `get (retrieve)` using `django-rest-framework` and AJAX.

But I have some problems in implementing `delete` (`Delete API` is ready).

Here is my idea :

HTML :

```
<div class="comment-meta">
    <a id="comment-delete" href="/api/posts/notice/2/comments/4/delete/">
        삭제
    </a>
</div>
```

JQuery :

```
var commentMetaElement = $(".comment-meta");
var commentDeleteElement = $(commentMetaElement).find("#comment-delete");
var commentDeleteURL = $(commentDeleteElement).attr('href');

$(commentDeleteElement).click(function(){
    alert($(this).attr('href'));
    $.ajax({
        url: commentDeleteURL,
        type: "DELETE",
        success: function(data){
            alert("done!");
        },
        error: function(data){
            console.log(textStatus);
        }
    });
});
```

And when I click the `a` tag, `alert` doesn't occur.

Also, when I insert the code `alert(commentDeleteURL);` after `var commentDeleteURL = $(commentDeleteElement).attr('href');`, it show: `undefined`.

I wonder whether I'm implementing it in right way.

First of all, I wonder it is right to create `a` tag for deleting...

Thanks :)

Comment: You don't need to wrap `commentMetaElement` and `commentDeleteElement` in `$(..)` - they are already jQuery objects.

Answer (score 0):

change this

```
$(commentDeleteElement).click(function(){
```

to

```
 $("#commmet-delete").click(function(){
```

Comment: I changed the code, and click the href, it accept `click` as `GET` method, not `DELETE` method, so it shows `"Method \"GET\" not allowed."`...

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#comment-delete").on('click', function(){
     var commentDeleteURL = $(this).attr("href");

      $.ajax({
         url: commentDeleteURL,
         type: "DELETE",
        success: function(data){
            alert("done!");
         },
        error: function(data){
            console.log(textStatus);
        }
      });
});
```

Comment: I changed the code, and click the href, it accept `click` as `GET` method, not `DELETE` method, so it shows `"Method \"GET\" not allowed."`...